# Directory error in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So, I've been trying to create a resource folder/directory for my java project in Intellij IDEA. For some reason I can't actually get this to work.

So now I go to create a directory under my helloworld package

and this error message shows up "failed to create directory (x location)"

but I go to check my folder where all my other stuff for the project is stored, and there is a folder there with the exact same name. Anybody got any idea what's going on here?

(I'd post pictures but apparently I need 10 reputation?? which I don't have. Sorry.)

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using? Also this sounds like a bug. Maybe it would be best to report it on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard

Comment: I believe I'm using the most recent version.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt community version

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt okay, so it appears to be better, I force closed the program, and restarted, and now all the folders have shown up.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I would still recommend to report it to JetBrains though. This seems like a bug in the IDE so any information you could provide to them (perhaps a log) could help them fix this problem so that it does not happen again.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt Yeah, I probably should

Answer (score 1):

before i same ploblem 
in my case, i use, Option on a right-click menu of a program icon that, when selected, allows the program to run with full administrator privileges.
after working 
my os windows 10